# SQL stored procedure won't execute on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I was trying to call a stored procedure getMarks() and display it on my php page. The code works well in phpmyadmin. However, when I tried to display it on my php page, it calls the undefined index:student_name.

This is my stored procedure getMarks():

```
BEGIN

    SET group_concat_max_len=5058;
    SET @condition = 'MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = ''@at'' AND assessmet_no = @an THEN assessment_marks END) as @at@an';

    SELECT @conditions := GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(@condition, '@at', assessment_type), '@an', assessmet_no))
    FROM studentmarks;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('
    SELECT student_name, ', @conditions, ' 
    FROM studentmarks
    GROUP BY student_name');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;


END
```

This is my php code:

```
$pstmt = 'call getMarks()';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($pstmt);

$stmt->execute();
$item = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then, I wanted to display the result like this on another php page:

```
<?php foreach($item as $marks): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $marks['student_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Unfortunately, the error undefined index:student_name is called.

This is how the result of my procedure looks like if I execute it on phpmyadmin:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  student_name |  QUIZ1     |   QUIZ2  |
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  thaqif       |  4.00      |   5.oo   |
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  ajis         |  4.00      |   5.00   |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

However, when I tried to run `var_dump($item)`, the result would be like this.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["@conditions := GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(@condition, '@at', assessment_type), '@an', assessmet_no))"]=> string(287) "MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = 'QUIZ' AND assessmet_no = 1 THEN assessment_marks END) as QUIZ1,MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = 'QUIZ' AND assessmet_no = 2 THEN assessment_marks END) as QUIZ2,MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = 'TEST' AND assessmet_no = 0 THEN assessment_marks END) as TEST0" } }
```